# Drag & drop animated indicator between carousel elements

Tags: android

I'm quite new to the Android development world, and need some ideas regarding some ways (if it's possible) in which I can implement the following:

Starting from a central element, I want to display other elements (icons) in a carousel style around it, and be able to initiate an action by a drag & drop gesture between the central element towards one of its satellites, and this action should be displayed as an animated arrow that is spawned upon starting the drag & drop gesture, follows the user movement, and is destroyed upon dropping on one of the satellites.

Is there a library or engine that allows such behavior? I looked it up on Google but with no success.

Many thanks!
[image]